# String printing excluding the first N characters

Tags: c, string, format, printf

I want to print my string which is "Something" **without the first N letters** inside the `printf` statement.

**Example 1**: I can do the "opposite" (`printf` just N first letters):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  char str[] = "Something";
  printf("%5s", str);
}
```

**Output**:`Somet`

**Expected Output**: `hing`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start the printing in the middle:

```
printf("%s", &str[5]);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, been searching this for a while

Answer (score 1):

You could try using pointer arithmetic to pass the address of the starting point in the string where you want the printing to begin. In a more general context, you will need to somehow check that the number of character you are skipping is less than the total length of the main string.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char str[]="Something";
    int numCharsToSkip = 5;

    printf("%s", (str + numCharsToSkip));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many way to select where to start printing in a buffer.  One potentially useful function, [strchr(const char *buf, char ch)](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strchr.htm), returns a pointer to the first occurrence of the `char` *ch*.   So, If you want to begin printing at the letter `h`, then call `strchr()` in this way:

For expected output `hing`, use:

```
char str[]="Something";
printf("%s", strchr(str, 'h');
```

Or, for expected output `omething`, use:

```
printf("%s", strchr(str, 'o');
```

Another useful function: [strstr(const char *source, const char *search)](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strstr.htm) returns a pointer to any sub-string, *search* existing in the *source* buffer, so is also useful if you want to begin printing at a particular word in a larger buffer, for example given:

```
char longerStr[] = "This is really something else";
char *token = strstr(longerStr, "thing");
if(token)    //test before using to prevent trying to print a nul pointer in the event
{            //"thing" is not found in buffer.
    printf("%s", token);//note using " ", not ' '
}
```